# What is the cleanest way of removing a control from a container?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm having a WinForms performance issue that might be related to the fact that I dynamically add and then remove hundreds of controls.

**EDIT {** 
The application displays a timeline which consists of controls representing historical events. Controls are added, removed or moved, depending on the time you jump to. The performance issues are not only during the addition and removal of controls (this I can live with), but even after I jump to a time with no historical events (meaning no controls are currently displayed). After jumping around and getting to a time where there are no events on the timeline, some activities in the GUI still take a long amount of time to complete, such as opening menus or opening dialog boxes. The strange thing is that other GUI activities, such as pressing buttons, do not stall. **}**

Although the memory consumption is perfectly stable, can it still be that there is an issue with freeing resources?

In order to remove a control, I do two things:

1. Unregister callbacks from all events,
2. Call `containerPanel.Controls.Remove(control)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have trouble due to GC pressure, that is that the garbage collector is running often due to many objects beeing created and then freed. when the GC runs all threads are stopped in their tracks (almost) and the app looks like its freezing

i dont think you're doing anything wrong with your removal code, but perhaps you can cache the controls somehow? can you tell us a bit more about you scenario?

-edit-

Based on your scenario, i'd suggest sidestepping the whole issue with removing controls and adding new ones and if possible reusing the controls that are already in the view, but switching out their data contexts (binding them to diffrent data) when the view changes. In wpf a common name for this approach is [UI-virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716879.aspx) but it can be applied to any ui framework, at least in principle

Another way around the problem might be to have empty place holder controls for the for all the positions in the timeline that you can scroll to immediately and then add content to as its loaded from disk or whereever. That way you would not have to affect the layout of the whole time line, you'd just fill in the particular slot the user is viewing. This would be even more effective if all the time-line-event-controls are all the same size, then the layout of the entire timeline would be completley unaffected)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I edited the question with the scenario.

Comment: PERFECT! I tried reusing old controls and it worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 6):

As you already observed, it isn't a memory problem. My guess is, that the problem is the simple fact, that your program needs to refresh the screen that often. If you remove and add those "hundreds of controls" in one batch, you can try to disable screen refresh until you are done.
You can do this using [`SuspendLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout.aspx) and [`ResumeLayout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y53zat12.aspx):

```
SuspendLayout();
for(...)
    AddControl(...);
ResumeLayout();
```

and

```
SuspendLayout();
for(...)
    RemoveControl(...);
ResumeLayout();
```

Comment: +1 for SuspendLayout. This is almost certainly what he needs. In addition, I wonder if the controls that are being added/removed so frequently can be, themselves, grouped in a [`Panel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) (or some other container) so that they can be removed as a single control (the `Panel`), and the replacements can be added as a new `Panel`? This should help to simplify things if not done already (add/pop one control out of the container rather than many; obviously the add code still needs to exist for them to the `Panel` itself).

Comment: @pickypg: Good idea with the panel, but we really don't know what the OP is doing here anyway with hundreds of controls. Furthermore, your suggestion is more an architecture improvement / code simplification than a performance optimization.

Comment: @Daniel Agreed. That's why I added to your answer as a comment :)

Comment: Assuming op is doing all this on the ui thread, isnt rendering already blocked by the add/remove calls? i thought Suspend/ResumeLayout only disabled Layout events [on the panel for example] specifically.. still, doing that will improve the perf of adding and removing so its a good idea all the same :)

Comment: @aL3891: This assumption is not correct. Every update to a control will trigger a UI refresh. Multiple updates will trigger multiple refreshes, even if they all are executed only after all the controls are added and the UI thread is idle again. Furthermore, you can't call those methods from a different thread or add controls to a form from a different thread: "Invalid cross-thread call".

Comment: i know about the cross thread exception, that is how infer that op is doing all this from the ui thread. i did not know however that the rendering engine still did multiple discreet updates like you describe when the ui thread idles.. you learn something every day :)

Comment: Actually the slow performance I'm experiencing isn't *during* the addition and removal of the controls, but *after they have been removed*. So `SuspendLayout()` doesn't seem to be the answer.

Comment: @Ilya: I suggest, you still try it, because as I have already written, the UI refresh very likely happens only after all controls have been removed. The other problem might be the GC continuously running like aL3891 pointed out.

Comment: Thanks for trying, @Daniel. I tried this, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2):

Removing lots of controls one at a time is really not something that WinForms is designed to do well.

Each call to `ControlCollection.Remove` results in a call to `ArrayList.RemoveAt`. If you are removing the last item in the collection this not too bad. If you are removing an item from the middle of the collection `Array.Copy` will get called to shuffle all of the items after that element in the `ArrayList`'s internal array down to fill the empty spot.

There are a couple of approaches you could try:

#### Remove all the controls then add back the ones you want to keep

```
ArrayList l = new ArrayList();
foreach (Control c in Controls){
    if (ShouldKeepControl(c))
        l.Add(c);
    else
        UnhookEvents(c);
}
SuspendLayout();
Controls.Clear();
Controls.AddRange((Control[])l.ToArray(typeof(Control)));
ResumeLayout();
```

#### Remove last to first

```
/* Example assumes your controls are in the best possible
   order for this technique. If they were mostly at the end
   with a few in the middle a modified version of this
   could still work. */
int i = Controls.Count - 1;
bool stillRemoving = true;
SuspendLayout();
while (stillRemoving && i >= 0){
    Control c = Controls[i];
    if (ShouldRemoveControl(c)){
        UnhookEvents(c);
        Controls.RemoveAt(i);
        i--;
    }else{
        stillRemoving = false;
    }
}
ResumeLayout();
```

The effectiveness of either approach will depend on how many controls you are keeping after removing a batch of controls and the order of the controls in the collection.

Comment: Thanks, @Jake. Your answer has been very informative, you've really taught me an important thing. It seems that this approach sped up the addition and removal of controls a little bit, but it didn't solve the slowness problem after the controls have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Control` implements `IDisposable` you should also Dispose the control after removing it from its container.

```
containerPanel.Controls.Remove(control);
control.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing I don't understand though: why isn't `Dispose()`  called by the garbage collector as part of the finalization after I remove the reference to the control from the `Controls` collection?

Comment: Because `IDisposable` is merely an interface, nothing more. But the controls finalizer most likely will call `Dispose`. The problem here is that the GC is non-deterministic, i.e. you don't know when it collects the controls

Comment: Thanks, @Joe and @Daniel. Unfortunately this didn't help either, I don't see any performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

When doing hundreds of small updates to the UI of a WinForm app there might be performance issues when the UI thread over and over again redraws the interface. This especially occurs if the updates are pushed from a background thread.

If this is the problem it can render the UI totally unusable for a while. The solution is to make the updates in a way that the UI doesn't redraw until all of the pending updates are done.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, 
this look funny but for me, the only solution which works fine for me was

```
  For i = 0 To 3 ' just to repeat it !!
            For Each con In splitContainer.Panel2.Controls
                splitContainer.Panel2.Controls.Remove(con)
                con.Dispose()
                'con.Visible = False
            Next
        Next
```

- using suspendLayout() and resumeLayout() methods !!!

Comment: Why the loop? And what's the connection between your code and your final comment?